# Edit Image Externally

Tags: rendering, image

When I render an image, the "Image" menu has an option to "Edit Externally" but I can't get it to work. Would love to render, then edit in Photoshop. Can anyone help? I've tried setting the  "image editor" in user preferences.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the associated image editing program in *User preferences > File* first. Next, make *sure* that the image is saved to disk (you can use <kbd>F3</kbd>) and it should work.

[image]

When saving, use *Save As Image* and untick *Save as Render* and *Copy* but keep *Relative Path*.

[image]

Comment: I have set this but no joy :( .I should have added this in my original message but I get an error when I click "Edit Externally": "Image path '.' not found, image may be packed or unsaved" However I have DEFINITELY just click "Save As Image" and saved the file in my project folder!

Comment: @user1841 See updated answer.

Comment: Tried unchecking box but still wrong. Noticed that if I do "Save As Image" (F3), save it, then immediately do "Save Image" (Alt-S) I get error "Cannot save image, path '' is not writeable". I would expect it to save it in the same place as F3. Obviously it's not looking in the correct place :(

Comment: SUPERSTAR! Works! I didn't have the "Relative Path" (thought we were just on different versions). It appears when unchecking "Copy" and makes all the difference! Thanks a million! Here are a few more exclamation marks for safety!!!

Comment: @user1841 This was an [old bug](http://developer.blender.org/T29062) that has come back somehow it seems. Reported and a developer has claimed it.